# Pick random element from array, but unique

Tags: java, arrays

I have array of countries. I want to pick 5 random countries from my array list, but I want them to be unique.
This is what I have so far:

```
String allCountries[] = {"Finland", "Latvia", "Poland", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"};

String country1 = (allCountries[new Random().nextInt(allCountries.length)]);
String country2 = (allCountries[new Random().nextInt(allCountries.length)]);
String country3 = (allCountries[new Random().nextInt(allCountries.length)]);
String country4 = (allCountries[new Random().nextInt(allCountries.length)]);
String country5 = (allCountries[new Random().nextInt(allCountries.length)]);
```

What is the best way to compare those strings while generating random elements?

**Edit:**

I expressed myself bad. The problem I have is that I don't want string country1, country 2 etc. to be same... so I want them to be always different.

**Solution:**

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(allCountries));
```

Comment: You **don't** want them to be unique?  If so why do you need to compare them, what you have should work fine.

Comment: Your title and question are conflicting. Do you or do you not want unique?

Comment: You don't or you do? Please clarify the contradicting title.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself bad... I will change the question.

Comment: @alex: Maybe convert that to an answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Shuffle the array and then slice the first 5 elements.

This will guarantee 5 unique random elements.

Comment: Excellent idea... I also added the code to my question. Thank you :)